# pseudocode for this program (Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have three sets, say:

```
a=[1 1 1 1];

b=[2 2 2];

c=[3 3];
```

Now, I have to find out all unique combinations by taking 3 elements from all sets..

So in matlab, I can do it:

```
>> a=[1 1 1 1];
>> b=[2 2 2];
>> c=[3 3];
>> all=[a b c];
>> nchoosek(all,3)
>> unique(nchoosek(all,3),'rows')
```

The o/p is:

```
     1     1     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     3
     1     2     2
     1     2     3
     1     3     3
     2     2     2
     2     2     3
     2     3     3
```

How to write the logic behind the program in pseudocode?

Comment: So what is the actual meaning of the sets? it looks like you have chosen three numbers out of `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]`...

Comment: I'd say you best start by explaining the algorithm in your own words.

Comment: Are you sure you're not meant to take all combinations created by taking one number out of each of the three sets?

Comment: What does it mean? A set can not have repeated elements!

Comment: In words, I want to find out a series of combinations by taking at most 3 elements in each combination. Now, it may be the case that, 3 elements came all from a..like 1 1 1, again it could also be the case that 2 elements from a and 1 element from b like 1 1 2..like this

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

- Create a dictionary of item counts.
- Recurse on this dictionary `k` times, taking care not to pick items that are not or no longer in the pool.
- When recursing, skip items that are smaller (by some criterion) than the current item in order to get a unique list.

In pseudocode:

```
function ucombok_rec(count, k, lowest)
{
    if (k == 0) return [[]];

    var res = [];

    for (item in count):
        if (item >= lowest && count[item] > 0) {
            count[item]--;

            var combo = ucombok_rec(count, k - 1, item);

            for (c in combo) res ~= [[item] ~ c];
            count[item]++;
        }

    return res;
}

function ucombok(s, k)
{
    if (!s) return [];                      // nothing to do

    var count = {};
    var lowest = min(s);                    // min. value in set
    for (item in s) count[item]++;          // create item counts

    return ucombok_rec(count, k, lowest);   // recurse
}
```

In this code, `[]` denotes a list or vector, `{}` a dictionary or map and the tilde `~` means list concatenation. The count decrements and increments around the recursion remove an item temporarily from the item pool.

In your example, where the pool is made up of three lists, you' d call the function like this:

```
c = ucombok(a ~  b ~  c, 3)
```